# How can enable only one container to expand on click?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use expand/collapse container, and everything works except one little detail. I want to restrict end users from opening multiple container at once. Ideally, I want only one container to be expanded at once.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some object to hold application state.  you could create a variable such as

```
var expanded = false;
```

then wrap your code above in a statement like so that when you click to expand an item

```
if (!expanded) {
    // proceed as normally
    expanded = true;
} else {
    // stop action from happening
    return;
}
```

EDIT:

you'll also want to changed expanded back to false when you click on the minus

EDIT EDIT:
I made some modifications to your link

http://jsfiddle.net/eo1Ljw97/

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the other large box elements like

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  if ($(".navBoxes").length > 0) {
    var html = document.getElementsByTagName("html").item(0);
    var hasCSS3 = (html.className.indexOf("no-csstransforms") == -1)

    $(".no-csstransforms .larger").toggleClass("undisplayed");
    $(".larger").children().toggleClass("undisplayed");

    // Expand nav box
    $(".nav.plus").click(function() {
      var smallerBox = $(this).closest(".navBox");
      var largerBox = smallerBox.next();
      var $ol = $(this).closest('.navBoxes').find('.navBox.larger').not(largerBox);

      if (hasCSS3) {
        //smallerBox.siblings(".smaller").toggleClass("contracted");
        //smallerBox.siblings(".smaller").toggleClass("hidden");
        //smallerBox.children().toggleClass("hidden");
        //smallerBox.toggleClass("expanded").delay(600).toggleClass("hidden");
        largerBox.toggleClass("atop").delay(600).toggleClass("hidden");
        $ol.removeClass('atop').addClass('hidden');
      } else {
        //smallerBox.toggleClass("undisplayed");
        //smallerBox.siblings(".smaller").toggleClass("undisplayed");
        largerBox.toggleClass("undisplayed");
        $ol.addClass('undisplayed')
      }


      largerBox.children().toggleClass("undisplayed");
      $ol.children().addClass("undisplayed");
      return false;
    });

    // Contract nav box
    $(".nav.minus").click(function() {
      var largerBox = $(this).parents(".navBox");
      var smallerBox = largerBox.prev();

      largerBox.children().toggleClass("undisplayed");

      if (hasCSS3) {
        largerBox.toggleClass("hidden");
        largerBox.toggleClass("atop")
          //smallerBox.toggleClass("hidden");
          //smallerBox.toggleClass("expanded");
          //smallerBox.children().toggleClass("hidden");
          //smallerBox.siblings(".smaller").toggleClass("hidden");
          //smallerBox.siblings(".smaller").toggleClass("contracted");
      } else {
        largerBox.toggleClass("undisplayed");
        //smallerBox.toggleClass("undisplayed");
        //smallerBox.siblings(".smaller").toggleClass("undisplayed");
      }

      return false;
    });
  }
  setOrgChartDimensions();
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.navBoxes .undisplayed {
  display: none;
}
.navBoxes .navBox {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
}
.navBoxes .navBox.smaller {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.navBoxes .navBox.smaller.atop {
  z-index: 4;
}
.navBoxes .navBox.larger {
  width: inherit;
  z-index: 1;
}
.navBoxes .navBox.hidden {
  opacity: 0.0;
}
.navBoxes .navBox.larger.atop {
  z-index: 3;
}
.navBoxes .navBox.larger .icon {
  float: left;
}
.navBoxes .navBox.smaller a {
  color: #fff;
}
.navBoxes .navBox.larger .title {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}
.navBoxes .navBox.larger .body {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.navBoxes .navBox.larger .body a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.navBoxes .navBox .nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 35px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.navBoxes .navBox .nav a {
  color: #fff;
}
.navBoxes .navBox .nav.plus {
  top: 110px;
  left: 110px;
}
.navBoxes .navBox .nav.minus {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}
.navBoxes .box1 {
  background-color: #185394;
  transform-origin: top left;
}
.navBoxes .box1.smaller:hover {
  background-color: #214872;
}
.navBoxes .box2 {
  background-color: #c94747;
  transform-origin: top right;
}
.navBoxes .box2.smaller:hover {
  background-color: #b24444;
}
.navBoxes .box2.smaller {
  margin-left: 180px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navBoxes">
  <div class="navBox box1 smaller">
    <div class="title"><a href="#">Heading 1</div>
  <div class="nav plus">
   <div class="sign"><a aria-expanded="false" href="/">more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="navBox box1 larger hidden">
  <div class="body">
    <p>- Some Text - Some Text - Some Text - Some Text - Some Text - Some Text - Some Text - Some Text - Some Text - Some Text - Some Text - Some Text -</p>
  </div>
  <div class="nav minus">
    <div class="sign"><a aria-expanded="true" href="/">less</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="navBox box2 smaller">
  <div class="title"><a href="#">Heading 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav plus">
    <div class="sign"><a aria-expanded="false" href="/">more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="navBox box2 larger hidden">
  <div class="body">
    <p>- Some Text - Some Text - Some Text - Some Text -</p>
  </div>
  <div class="nav minus">
    <div class="sign"><a aria-expanded="true" href="/">less</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```